# Adding two levels of groupings into highcharts hplot with Shiny

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I'm creating a Shiny app that allows users to select several different options of stores to show. Each time a new store is checked, I'm attempting to show two line graphs - number of children who visit by time of day and number of adults. Using ggplot2 this is relatively simple, I just add two geom_lines --

```
base_E <- ggplot(data=store) + geom_line(aes(x=time, y=child_use, group=branch, colour=branch, linetype="Child")) + geom_line(aes(x=time, y=adult_use, group=branch, colour=branch, linetype="Adult"))
base_E <- base_E + xlab("Time of Day") + ylab("Num visitors") + scale_linetype_manual(name="", values=c("Child" = 1, "Adult"=2)) + scale_colour_discrete(name="Branch")  + ggtitle("title") + scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks("1 hour"), labels=date_format("%H:%M")) + ylim(0,100)
```

However, when I attempt to recreate this using RCharts and hplot, I have found no way to have two levels of grouping. I want to have each branch be a different color, with one solid line and one dashed line.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: So basically you need to have a second 'y' axis? If this is so you should probably reformulate the question to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I'm not looking for a second y axis though. Both should be on the same y axis, just one needs to be dotted and one solid. In the ggplot2 example, it ends up creating basically two legends, one with the color representing the branch and another with either solid or dotted for child/adult. Both are on the same scale

Comment: Can you post some example data? Also, the code you tried using hplot?